# How to use nano's Redo shortcut (Meta+E) in MATE terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop, nano

I'm using:

- Debian bullseye with its MATE desktop environment
- MATE caja 1.22.1
- MATE Terminal 1.22.1
- GNU nano, version 4.3

In nano, Redo is mapped to `Meta+E`. In `Keyboard Preferences` I have selected "German German (no dead keys)" and in the `Keyboard Layout Options` under `Alt/Win key behaviour`, I have selected `Meta is mapped to Left Win`.

When I press `Alt+E` in a nano running in a MATE Terminal, it opens the `Edit` menu of the terminal window. When I press `Meta+E` (that is, the left logo key and E) anywhere, Caja is opened to the home directory.

I have not found any way to disable either of these shortcuts to enable me to use nano's Undo function. In `Preferences` → `Keyboard Shortcuts`, the `Meta+E` shortcut (or Super, or Win, or Logo) is not listed. In MATE Terminal's `Edit` → `Keyboard Shortcuts...` the `Alt+E` shortcut is not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Esc+E` works. According to the nano online help:

> Meta-key sequences are notated with 'M-' and can be entered using
>   either the Alt, Cmd, or Esc key, depending on your keyboard setup.